# Python: any() to check if attribute in List of Objects matches a list

Tags: python, data-structures, iterator, generator

I have a List of objects returned from SQLAlchemy Query

```
projects =
    [
        {'project_id': 1, 'project_name': 'A'},
        {'project_id': 2, 'project_name': 'B'},
        {'project_id': 3, 'project_name': 'C'},
        {'project_id': 4, 'project_name': 'D'},
        {'project_id': 5, 'project_name': 'E'},
        {'project_id': 6, 'project_name': 'F'}
    ]
```

I want to make sure the list of objects has the project name in this list:

```
project_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

If it is just a single value, I can use

```
any(p.project_name == "A" for p in projects)
```

How can I do a similar comparison with a List? Something like:

```
any(p.project_name in project_list for p in projects)
```

The code above works, but I suspect `any()` returns `True` when as soon as there is a single match.

### Workaround

For now, I am extracting the object attribute into a new list, convert both lists into sets and compare them.

```
project_names = [project.project_name for project in projects]
assert set(project_list) <= set(project_names)
```

This works, but will be inefficient with a complex object and long list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of doing it via `set` is fine, and much better than any nested loop approach. Why do you think it's inefficient?

Minor optimizations would be to create the project set directly via generator expression, instead of extracting a temporary list:

```
project_set = set(p.project_name for p in projects)
```

And then using `all` instead of making a set out of the `project_list`:

```
assert all(p in project_set for p in project_list)
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `all`:

```
all(any(p_name==p.project_name for p in projects) for p_name in projects_list)
```

Or more readable:

```
appears = lambda p_name: any(p_name==p.project_name for p in projects)
all(appears(p_name) for p_name in projects_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need *short circuit* behaviour: Iterate through the list of objects; each time you find one you care about add it to a set; as soon as that set is *full* return `True`; else return `False`.

```
def f(projects, project_list):
    project_list = set(project_list)
    seen = set()
    for p in projects:
        if p.project_name in project_list:
            seen.update(p.project_name)
            if seen == project_list:
                return True
    return False
```

Sorry, no pithy one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You might like the following

```
'Project name' in [p.project_name for p in projects]
```